# App crashes after passing data from a recyclerview to another activity

Tags: android-recyclerview

2020-02-06 16:24:29.196 2461-2461/com.finix.betsmarttips E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.finix.betsmarttips, PID: 2461
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.finix.betsmarttips/com.finix.betsmarttips.GalleryActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.finix.betsmarttips.GalleryActivity$4.onSuccess(GalleryActivity.java:92)
        at com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator.into(RequestCreator.java:657)
        at com.finix.betsmarttips.GalleryActivity.getIncomingIntent(GalleryActivity.java:89)
        at com.finix.betsmarttips.GalleryActivity.onCreate(GalleryActivity.java:65)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more of your code. But based on the logs you are trying to access the visibility of a view that is null. Check what view are you trying to access here `GalleryActivity.java:92`